# OpenCL :Access proper index by using globalid(.)

Tags: opencv, opencl

Hi,
I am coding in OpenCL.
I am converting a "C function" having 2D array starting from i=1 and j=1 .PFB .

```
cv::Mat input; //Input :having some data in it ..
//Image input size is :input.rows=288 ,input.cols =640
cv::Mat output(input.rows-2,input.cols-2,CV_32F); //Output buffer
//Image output size is :output.rows=286 ,output.cols =638
```

This is a code Which I want to modify in OpenCL:

```
for(int i=1;i<output.rows-1;i++)
{
  for(int j=1;j<output.cols-1;j++)
    {
        float xVal = input.at<uchar>(i-1,j-1)-input.at<uchar>(i-1,j+1)+ 2*(input.at<uchar>(i,j-1)-input.at<uchar>(i,j+1))+input.at<uchar>(i+1,j-1) - input.at<uchar>(i+1,j+1);
        float yVal = input.at<uchar>(i-1,j-1) - input.at<uchar>(i+1,j-1)+ 2*(input.at<uchar>(i-1,j)   - input.at<uchar>(i+1,j))+input.at<uchar>(i-1,j+1)-input.at<uchar>(i+1,j+1);
        output.at<float>(i-1,j-1) = xVal*xVal+yVal*yVal;
    }
}
```

...
Host code :

```
//Input Image size is :input.rows=288 ,input.cols =640 
//Output Image size is :output.rows=286 ,output.cols =638 
 OclStr->global_work_size[0] =(input.cols);
 OclStr->global_work_size[1] =(input.rows);

 size_t outBufSize = (output.rows) * (output.cols) * 4;//4 as I am copying all 4 uchar values into one float variable space

    cl_mem cl_input_buffer = clCreateBuffer(
        OclStr->context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR ,
        (input.rows) * (input.cols),
        static_cast<void *>(input.data), &OclStr->returnstatus);

    cl_mem cl_output_buffer = clCreateBuffer(
        OclStr->context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY| CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR , 
        (output.rows) * (output.cols) * sizeof(float), 
        static_cast<void *>(output.data), &OclStr->returnstatus);

OclStr->returnstatus = clSetKernelArg(OclStr->objkernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cl_input_buffer);
OclStr->returnstatus = clSetKernelArg(OclStr->objkernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cl_output_buffer); 

    OclStr->returnstatus = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
        OclStr->command_queue, 
        OclStr->objkernel, 
        2, 
        NULL, 
        OclStr->global_work_size, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        NULL
        );
clEnqueueMapBuffer(OclStr->command_queue, cl_output_buffer, true, CL_MAP_READ, 0, outBufSize, 0, NULL, NULL, &OclStr->returnstatus);
```

kernel Code :

```
__kernel void Sobel_uchar (__global uchar *pSrc, __global float *pDstImage)              
{                                                                                      
const uint cols = get_global_id(0)+1;                                              
const uint rows = get_global_id(1)+1;                                              
const uint width= get_global_size(0);                                              
uchar Opsoble[8];                                                                  
Opsoble[0] = pSrc[(cols-1)+((rows-1)*width)];                           
Opsoble[1] = pSrc[(cols+1)+((rows-1)*width)];                           
Opsoble[2] = pSrc[(cols-1)+((rows+0)*width)];                           
Opsoble[3] = pSrc[(cols+1)+((rows+0)*width)];                           
Opsoble[4] = pSrc[(cols-1)+((rows+1)*width)];                           
Opsoble[5] = pSrc[(cols+1)+((rows+1)*width)];                           
Opsoble[6] = pSrc[(cols+0)+((rows-1)*width)];                           
Opsoble[7] = pSrc[(cols+0)+((rows+1)*width)];                           
float gx =   Opsoble[0]-Opsoble[1]+2*(Opsoble[2]-Opsoble[3])+Opsoble[4]-Opsoble[5];
float gy =   Opsoble[0]-Opsoble[4]+2*(Opsoble[6]-Opsoble[7])+Opsoble[1]-Opsoble[5];
pDstImage[(cols-1)+(rows-1)*width] = gx*gx + gy*gy;                                

    }
```

Here I am not able to get the output as expected. 
I am having some questions that

1. My for loop is starting from i=1 instead of zero, then How can I get proper index by using the global_id() in x and y direction
2. What is going wrong in my above kernel code :(

I am suspecting there is a problem in buffer stride but not able to further break my head as already broke it throughout a day :(
I have observed that with below logic output is skipping one or two frames after some 7/8 frames sequence.
I have added the screen shot of my output which is compared with the reference output.
My above logic is doing partial sobelling on my input .I changed the width as -

```
const uint width = get_global_size(0)+1;
```

PFB

Your suggestions are most welcome !!!
[image]

Comment: For the first question just change `const uint i = get_global_id(0);` to `const uint i = get_global_id(0) + 1;` and adjust global work size correspondingly.

Comment: pDstImage[(i-1)*width +(j-1)] = gx*gx + gy*gy ;   shouıldnyt this be i,j instead of i-1, j-1

Comment: You can have look at my output above after changing my code base as per suggestions !!

Comment: can you post a bit more detail about your host program please? work group size, global size, setKernelArgs...

Comment: I have added most of the information in my question ..I am getting some full size output but this is not proper output as like reference !!:(

Comment: was your original output tested to be correct? I am a bit confused by the code you posted originally. 'i' is looping over the row count, so it should represent the vertical axis. 'j' is looping over columns, and therefore should be used as the horizontal axis.   for(int i=1;i<output.rows-1;i++)
{
  for(int j=1;j<output.cols-1;j++)
...

Comment: mfa,I have just updated my kernel code and host code in my question ..I got some little bit good output..But I am suspecting on the stride issue ..Can You help me in that .Now what ever is the code base is the exact one that I am trying to run .

Comment: I think that if your image output is `(xsize-2, ysize-2)` your kernel launch sizes should be `cl::NDRange(xsize-2, ysize-2)`. And, inside the kernel use `const uint width = get_global_size(0)+2;` Otherwise, you will shift your results by +2 every line (You can notice this error effect, since the OCL output does not have black line at the right side). Think that, the OpenCL worker sizes have to be related to the output size, not the input. Then adapt their indexes to the input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be fetching values in (y,x) format in your opencl version. Also, you need to add 1 to the global id to replicate your for loops starting from 1 rather than 0.

I don't know why there is an unused iOffset variable. Maybe your bug is related to this? I removed it in my version.

Does this kernel work better for you?

```
__kernel void simple(__global uchar *pSrc, __global float *pDstImage)              
{                                                                                      
   const uint i = get_global_id(0) +1;                                                  
   const uint j = get_global_id(1) +1;                                                  
   const uint width = get_global_size(0) +2;                                              

   uchar Opsoble[8];                                                                   
   Opsoble[0] = pSrc[(i-1) + (j - 1)*width];                                           
   Opsoble[1] = pSrc[(i-1) + (j + 1)*width];                                           
   Opsoble[2] = pSrc[i + (j-1)*width];                                                 
   Opsoble[3] = pSrc[i + (j+1)*width];                                                 
   Opsoble[4] = pSrc[(i+1) + (j - 1)*width];                                           
   Opsoble[5] = pSrc[(i+1) + (j + 1)*width];                                           
   Opsoble[6] = pSrc[(i-1) + (j)*width];                                               
   Opsoble[7] = pSrc[(i+1) + (j)*width];
   float gx =   Opsoble[0]-Opsoble[1]+2*(Opsoble[2]-Opsoble[3])+Opsoble[4]-Opsoble[5]; 
   float gy =   Opsoble[0]-Opsoble[4]+2*(Opsoble[6]-Opsoble[7])+Opsoble[1]-Opsoble[5]; 
   pDstImage[(i-1) + (j-1)*width] = gx*gx + gy*gy ;                                     
}
```

Comment: Hi mfa,With your tricks I did the changes .But I did not get the exact output as like reference .I chnaged the width as  const uint width = get_global_size(0)+1;

Comment: Is the output better if you try this in your host code?
 OclStr->global_work_size[0] =(output.rows);
 OclStr->global_work_size[1] =(output.cols);

Comment: No luck...am not getting output as like reference output as shown in figure (with for loop)..no luck...:(

Comment: Hi mfa,I have updated the screen shot of the output with OclStr->global_work_size[0] =(output.rows); OclStr->global_work_size[1] =(output.cols);This is far away from the actual ref output

Comment: try const uint width = get_global_size(0)+2; this will account for the 1px boarder. I updated the answer code with this change.

Comment: Mfa..instead of adding 2 in width calculation, what I did was I took global work size equal to the input cols and rows which are greater that output cols and rows by two...it worked...but no luck in stide calculation...still output is same as shown in screenshot (image1)

Comment: mfa,I modified the code with const uint width= get_global_size(0)+2;  and updated my question with output screen shot

Comment: output looks similar to the other skewed one. did you set the global work dimensions back to 286x638 along with the width+2 change?

Comment: I think he didn't. Since with the +2 the black line is shown, so that part is ok, but the skew is even more noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit apprehensive about posting an answer suggesting optimizations to your kernel, seeing as the original output has not been reproduced exactly as of yet. There is a major improvement available to be made for problems related to image processing/filtering.

Using local memory will help you out by reducing the number of global reads by a factor of eight, as well as grouping the global writes together for potential gains with the single write-per-pixel output.

The kernel below reads a block of up to 34x34 from pSrc, and outputs a 32x32(max) area of the pDstImage. I hope the comments in the code are enough to guide you in using the kernel. I have not been able to give this a complete test, so there could be changes required. Any comments are appreciated as well.

```
__kernel void sobel_uchar_wlocal (__global uchar *pSrc, __global float *pDstImage, __global uint2 dimDstImage)
{
    //call this kernel 1-dimensional work group size: 32x1
    //calculates 32x32 region of output with 32 work items

    const uint wid = get_local_id(0);
    const uint wid_1 = wid+1; // corrected for the calculation step
    const uint2 gid = (uint2)(get_group_id(0),get_group_id(1));
    const uint localDim = get_local_size(0);

    const uint2 globalTopLeft = (uint2)(localDim * gid.x, localDim * gid.y); //position in pSrc to copy from/to

    //dimLocalBuff is used for the right and bottom edges of the image, where the work group may run over the border
    const uint2 dimLocalBuff = (uint2)(localDim,localDim);
    if(dimDstImage.x - globalTopLeft.x < dimLocalBuff.x){
        dimLocalBuff.x = dimDstImage.x - globalTopLeft.x;
    }
    if(dimDstImage.y - globalTopLeft.y < dimLocalBuff.y){
        dimLocalBuff.y = dimDstImage.y - globalTopLeft.y;
    }

    int i,j;

    //save region of data into local memory
    __local uchar srcBuff[34][34]; //34^2 uchar = 1156 bytes
    for(j=-1;j<dimLocalBuff.y+1;j++){
        for(i=x-1;i<dimLocalBuff.x+1;i+=localDim){
            srcBuff[i+1][j+1] = pSrc[globalTopLeft.x+i][globalTopLeft.y+j];
        }
    }
    mem_fence(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    //compute output and store locally
    __local float dstBuff[32][32]; //32^2 float = 4096 bytes
    if(wid_1 < dimLocalBuff.x){
        for(i=0;i<dimLocalBuff.y;i++){
            float gx = srcBuff[(wid_1-1)+ (i - 1)]-srcBuff[(wid_1-1)+ (i + 1)]+2*(srcBuff[wid_1+ (i-1)]-srcBuff[wid_1+ (i+1)])+srcBuff[(wid_1+1)+ (i - 1)]-srcBuff[(wid_1+1)+ (i + 1)]; 
            float gy = srcBuff[(wid_1-1)+ (i - 1)]-srcBuff[(wid_1+1)+ (i - 1)]+2*(srcBuff[(wid_1-1)+ (i)]-srcBuff[(wid_1+1)+ (i)])+srcBuff[(wid_1-1)+ (i + 1)]-srcBuff[(wid_1+1)+ (i + 1)]; 
            dstBuff[wid][i] = gx*gx + gy*gy;
        }
    }
    mem_fence(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    //copy results to output
    for(j=0;j<dimLocalBuff.y;j++){
        for(i=0;i<dimLocalBuff.x;i+=localDim){
            srcBuff[i][j] = pSrc[globalTopLeft.x+i][globalTopLeft.y+j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would skip the last step and write directly to global memory. That way the writing latency to global can be interleaved with the gx gy operation. By saving it to local it might be faster at that time, but the compiler cannot understand that the data is not being modified by other threads, so waits until the fence to dump all the values to global. However, shouldn't have a big speed impact.

Comment: Probably worth trying both methods. delaying the write may only have a tiny benefit after all.